# Meaning of "habe mir das Papier nicht mehr durchgelesen"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From *Der Spiegel*:

> Schabowski taucht erst kurz vor der Pressekonferenz wieder auf, die er am Abend geben soll. Krenz drückt ihm die neue Reiseregelung in die Hand. "Ich bin ins Pressezentrum gefahren und **habe mir das Papier nicht mehr durchgelesen**", wird Schabowski wenige Monate später sagen. Da hat er bereits Weltgeschichte geschrieben. Indem er unabsichtlich am Abend des 9. November die Berliner Mauer öffnete.

Why is the usage of "nicht mehr" in the bolded sentence appropriate here? The meaning seems to be

> I came into the press center and haven't read the paper.

which makes more sense with

> habe mir das Papier nicht durchgelesen.

or

> habe mir das Papier noch nicht durchgelesen.

Comment: Short for: "Ich hatte **nicht mehr** die Zeit, das Papier zu lesen" (und habe es daher nicht getan, obwohl ich es vorhatte).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "I went to the press center and did not **get around** to reading the paper [before holding the press conference]".